# Weird Scrolling Issue Using UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, scroll

I am a working UINavigationController pushing two different UITableViews on and off the stack.  All of my functionality is working correctly except scrolling.  When either table is scrolled above the top row, or below the bottom row, it stays there exposing the margin above/below the table.  I am looking for the table to "bounce" back so that only the table is visible and not the white space area beyond - just like any other iPhone app.

One of my UITableViews is being loaded by NIB and the other is being created programatically - both of which have the exact same result.  I have tried all the bounce and scrolling settings in the Nib, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Please let me know if I can be more specific in detailing my problem.

Thanks,

-Scott

I wanted to add a bit more information since I am still unable to figure out this problem.  I should point out that the app I am trying to add this NavigationController to is NOT the main view.  I have a SettingsViewController that uses a Nib to get loaded.  Within that controller, I am wanting to create a new navigation based set of views.  So From inside my SettingsViewController, if the user taps a button, I...

Within my button selector:

```
TextListViewController *controller = [[TextListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

controller.title = @"Test Table View"; 
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[controller release];

The above code works perfectly in every way except scrolling.  I am able to process all the delegate methods and push new controllers onto the stack.  The ONLY issue I am having is that the root controller (and every other controller pushed) will not scroll correctly.

In every case, it allows me to scroll past the top and bottom of the table and does not snap back like it should.  It also does not have a free-wheel feel to it when you flick scroll.  Instead, it stops as soon as you remove your finger no matter how fast you scrolled.  Very odd.

I have tried creating another project using the Navigation template - and of course it works fine - but the template assumes the NavigationController's view is attached all the time - which is not my case.  I am creating all of this on the fly within a standard ViewController.

Thanks for your help Kevin, but I am still looking for some help here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed the issue and it had nothing to do with how I was adding the UITableView to the UINavigationController or in how I was instantiating the view.  It turns out it was completely unrelated to any of that.

I am using a tight while loop to process my game loop.  I needed a way to process OS messages in the loop to keep touches and other events from being blocked.  Here is what I was using in the middle of my loop:

```
while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```

Up until this scrolling problem, I had no problems with this implementation at all.  For whatever reason, this is breaking the scrolling functionality with UITableView.

I changed my game loop so the above code is not needed and everything started working.

Thanks...

Comment: I had the same thing when running a custom NSRunLoop in default mode. Refactoring my code to not need that fixed the issue, and my table view now scrolls correctly in a UINavigationController presented modally. Thank!

Comment: do you have any idea why this might be an issue? I'm having the same problem but don't think I can solve it by refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`, whose property `bounces` is the key.  Here's the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces).  By default it is `YES`, though.  Did you check this one?

Comment: Yes, I checked that and it is set to YES.  The docs also say that property, if set to NO, will not allow the view to be scrolled past the end of the content.  In my case, it is scrolling past in both directions. 

Could this haves something to do with the fact that my UITableView is hooked up to a UINavigationController?  Thanks...

Comment: I forgot to mention, when scrolling a list of 20+ items, the scrolling is not fluid.  Normally when you move you finger down fast and remove it from the screen, the scrolling continues for a few rows.  in my case, the scrolling stops immediately after removing my finger no matter how fast I scrolled.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and comments seem to suggest that you are attaching a `UITableView` to your `UINavigationController` in some way other than by pushing a `UITableViewController`.  If you're not doing it that way, you really should.

In general, if you can push a child view controller onto a `UINavigationController`, then you can also use the child view controller by itself just to test it out.  Try making your `UITableViewController`'s view the root view of your window, and see if that does what you expect.  That way you can isolate the problem to either the table view part or the navigation part.

Comment: Kevin,

I am creating a UINavigationController and attaching a UITableViewController using the Nav's initWithRootViewController.

TextListViewController *controller = [[TextListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextListViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.title = @"Title Text";    
 
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self sesentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
 
[controller release];

Is this correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow, that's ugly.  Not sure how to show you the code in a readable format on this forum.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

-Scott

Comment: Hmm.  It looked correct to me…  Try comparing versus a new project using the navigation / table view template.  It should do basically what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue as you which as you state above was related to the way you were calling the runloop:

```
while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```

Seems like DefaultMode is the wrong thing to be waiting on, I changed my code to wait on UITrackingRunLoopMode and the TableView worked correctly. In my case I used:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

And everything worked correctly.